# Saving dialog content before closing it

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'm making a dialog containing a list of items, each of which includes an editable text field.

I'd like to save the contents of edited text fields to a SQLite database on dialog close.

How would I do that? There seems to be no such thing as an onClose listener in Flutter and once the dialog is closed, I won't be able to retrieve the text from text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You have not shared any code - so i share a minimal example of what you intend to do.

Data can be passed with the use of `Navigator`.

```
class DemoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DemoAppState createState() {
    return new DemoAppState();
  }
}

class DemoAppState extends State<DemoApp> {
  String val = 'Empty';

  TextEditingController cntrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    cntrl.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Value is -- $val'),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              val = await showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    cntrl.clear();
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Enter Value'),
                      content: TextField(
                        controller: cntrl,
                      ),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context, cntrl.text);
                            },
                            child: Text('Save')),
                      ],
                    );
                  });
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Text('Edit Value'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can return that value without a button press? (Just closing the dialog by tapping the border around it)

Comment: we actually need to pass value to - `Navigator.pop` - in the other case (Just closing the dialog by tapping the border around it) it's not happening. so no not directly. you can add - `barrierDismissible: false,` in `showDialog` so user do press button to close the dialog. @TinMan